# Assign a post to a term when adding or editing a term

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I want to be able to assign a post to a term when adding or editing a term. I thought it might be possible to do this with ACF save_post. Can you help me for the php code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand Acf Save post saves your $_POST data. Not sure if you  mean post as in blog posts or if you're referring to $_POST data from a form.

As an alternative, If you're using MYSQLI in your website you can assign your $_POST data to an assoc array when you submit. So alongside your other database entries, you can write code to assign these $_POST variables to an assoc. array of terms you've defined.

First, I'd suggest created a database of your terms that you can edit. Write HTML code for your posts that asks for both Post_title and relevant term. This way you add values to your posts based on terms and later create code to search your database for posts that use those terms (similar to how tags work).

So to remember, you need to create a database that has a value for post_title and terms and a seperate database for your posts alone. The second database essentially acts as an assoc. array between posts and terms.

```
<div>
<form action='' method="post">
  <div>
  <?php

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     // If you have additional text input/images or anything else, create a variable based on the 'name' you assigned for it in your html field. e.g 
     $post_text=$_POST['post_text'];
    
     $post_title= $_POST['post_title'];
     $post_term = $_POST['terms'];

     // A small check to make sure we don't send empty posts without terms. If you don't want this remove this part of the code

     if ($post_term == "" || $post_title == "") {
         echo "<h4> The field is empty</h4>";

     } 
     // Check ends here. Again if you don't want this check just change the following else statement to an if

     else {
     
     // Field_1/Field_2 are the specific names of these fields in your database. 'yourpostsdatabasename' as the name implies is the specific name of your database on MYSQLI. Same applies for the terms database

     $addtoposts= "INSERT INTO yourpostsdatabasename (field_1,field_2)   VALUES ('$post_title', '$post_text')";

     $addtoterms= "INSERT INTO yourtermsdatabase (field_1,field_2) VALUES ('$post_term', '$post_title')";

     $postsquery=mysqli_query($connection,$addtoposts);
     $termsquery=mysqli_query($connection,$addtoterms);
     }
    }
   ?>
     
  <label for="post_title">Post Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="post_title">
  // You can add more input fields for post text etc, Just make corresponding titles and fields in your database to accomodate this data
  <label for="terms">Terms></label>
  <input type="text" name="terms">
  </div>
  <div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit"> Add Post </button>
  </div>

   //To show what terms are associated to what posts, you can write html to display a terms table like so

  <div>
  <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Post Title</td>
    <td>Post Term</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
      $term_search="SELECT * FROM yourtermsdatabasename";
      $term_query=mysqli($connection,$term_search);


    // Remember, the values field_1, field_2 have to be the exact names of the corresponding fields on your terms database. Along with the exact name of your database for the variable $term_search above.

      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($term_query)){
       $post_name=$row['field_1'];
       $term=$row['field_2'];
   
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>{$post_name}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$term}</td>";
       echo "</tr>";

       }

      ?>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I use Wordpress for my website. ACF is a Wordpress plugin.